# Windows: Who is calling TlsAlloc BEFORE my application loads?

Tags: windows, dynamic-memory-allocation, thread-local-storage

I have an application that uses a fair number (don't ask!) of Thread Local Storage variables.   It has been operable without issue for almost a decade ... until a recent surprise.

A customer has a laptop running Windows7 (64 bit)... and on his system, the TLS allocation fails.  (My problem isn't exactly this, but close enough).  He claims his system is pretty standard; he has a ZoneAlarm but claims everything else is stock; take that with a grain of salt).   How do I find out who or what is allocating other TLS slots (and running me effectively out of slots)?

The application is a console standalone application and fairly vanilla:  open/read/write files, some multithreading, practically nothing else, so I expect only the basic Windows DLLs to be actively involved.     I know that some DLLs (even the Windows ones) may service thread-based activities and so will allocate their own TLS slots, and that's OK.  But I don't expect that lots and lots are allocated by anything sane.  Is there something else that can insert itself into my process space as part of my application startup (maybe a firewall)?

How many TLS slots should be allocated in a typical process when it starts up? Where is the demand coming from?  Can I trace TLS calls to see who is allocating them somehow?

**EDIT: Jan 1, 2013:**  Having some experience now, and having my tool report the TLS demand when it starts, I see something like the following:

- Win XP 64 8 cores 16 Gb RAM:  3 TLS variables busy
- Windows Vista 32 4 Gb RAM:  4 TLS variables busy
- Win 7 Pro: 4 cores 8 Gb RAM:  7 TLS variables busy
- Win 7 (French version):  2 cores, 4 GB:  minimum of 25 TLS variables busy, more in some configurations

We're checking on Windows 8, but its TLS demand appears to be higher.  But what on earth accounts for the huge difference between the two Windows 7 systems?  Any why is there any need for TLS variables (presumably for DLLs to store thread state) *before* my application starts running, especially considering there was no need for in earlier version of Windows?

If it helps, we are running a 32 bit application.

Comment: Are you sure this is what is happening?  The upper limit on TLS indexes is 1088; that's a huge amount.  I don't know if you can trace TLS calls; debugging it seems like the most straightforward approach if possible.  Failing that, you could attempt to hook the TlsAlloc() function.

Comment: I'm not getting 1088 indexes allocated, but I am getting allocations I don't expect.  The real problem is more complex than I've explained, but what matters is that a surprising number of TLSAllocs are being made by something that isn't our application, before ours tries, and I'd like to know what.   I don't know what you mean by "debugging" this; the TLSAllocs made seem to have been done before our application does anything serious.  I suppose I could look to see if they occur before main() gets control.  "Attempt" to hook TlsAlloc?   How do I do that?

Comment: By "debugging" I meant running it in windbg and breaking on calls to TlsAlloc(); I don't know if that's practical to do on a customer's machine, though.  Here's a good [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2009/03/24/tlsalloc-failed-with-tls-out-of-indexes.aspx) to scripting adplus to dump the stack traces on calls to TlsAlloc().  For hooking you can use [detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), though if the calls are happening before your main() function is called that's not going to help you.

Comment: To "break on *calls* *to* TlsAlloc", you have *find* those calls.  I know where they are in my code, by my code isn't the problem.  I can imagine breaking on the TlsAlloc entry, if Windows will let me do that. (Wouldn't the OS code in my address space be write protected?) I'll go read about "detours".

Comment: It appears that ZoneAlarm significantly aggravates the problem.  With it removed, small object file versions of our application that did not run now run fine, but bigger versions (simply more object code?  object code from a another path?) still fail.  Yes, its pretty weird.